# USB Ethernet Adapter in USB 2.0 Port

Tags: usb, ethernet, internet-speed, fiber

I recently upgraded my internet plan with my ISP and I got a 300Mb/s fiber connection.

What I noticed is that my laptop only supports up to 100Mb/s ethernet speeds, so I want to get a USB ethernet adapter to use.

The question is will a USB 2.0 port be able to support the full speed of my plan?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The short answer is NO for any USB2.0 adapter. A t best it'll be the same as the one you can get from your current Ethernet device.